# I want to make the input field has unique value

Tags: javascript, php, html

let us say that there is 5 input field for page (A)

```
<form class="classesName" action="action.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="class1" placeholder="Class Name1?" required="">
     <input type="text" name="class2" placeholder="Class Name2?" required="">
     <input type="text" name="class3" placeholder="Class Name3?" required="">
     <input type="text" name="class4" placeholder="Class Name4?" required="">
     <input type="text" name="class5" placeholder="Class Name5?" required="">
</form>
```

I want the user to fill all the fields BUT it must be unique class name for each field

so he can't fill

> class a
>
> class b
>
> class a < this one is duplicated so it should display an error message
>
> class c
>
> class d

I think I can make if statement in the action.php page to check is there a duplication in the submitted field or not

but I don't want all the other values to be lost when I reload this page again to display the error for him

is there like a property in html5 or anything like that ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var frm = document.querySelector('form.classesName');
var inputs = frm.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

frm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var classArr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(classArr.indexOf(inputs[i].value) != -1) {
            inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            return false;
        }
        else
            classArr.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
    frm.submit();
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/70nkhthc/)

Answer (score 4):

No, this cannot be done with HTML5 alone. You'll have to write some JavaScript to make this happen. The JavaScript code should check all the values and if any two are identical prevent the form from submitting successfully.

Comment: thanks, is this could happen in javaScript without reloading the page ?

Comment: Yes that's one of the things javascript is really helpful for

Answer (score 4):

In this case you could use javascript to validate the fields every time the user fills out a textbox. Here is an example:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('change',function(){
    var arr = [];
    $siblings = $(this).siblings();
    $.each($siblings, function (i, key) {
       arr.push($(key).val()); 
    });
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), arr) !== -1)
    {
        alert("duplicate has been found");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x66j3qw3/

Comment: Very nice answer, little tweaking required but spot on.

Comment: You can also move this handler to form submission event since that's when they want the validation to occur and stop submission if there is a duplicate. Currently it won't stop form submission.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but only one thing is missing is that it will be submitted even with the duplication, thank you